# PROLOG list tasks for different elements

Tags: list, prolog

I am struggling with some PROLOG tasks at this moment and I cannot seem to get my predicates working the way I want them to.

I was asked to formulate two different predicates:

1. Check if X isn't an element of a list L.

**not_el(X, L)**

So for example if I ask the program I'd expect an output like this:

```
?- not_el(5, [3,4,5,6,7]).
X=false;
```

2. Put out the last but one element X in a list L.

**lastbutone_el(X, L)**
expecting an outcome like this:

> ```
> ?- lastbutone_el(X, [3,4,5,6,7]).
> X = 6;
> ```

Can anybody help me formulate the correct predicates to get outcomes like that?

Comment: Can you please show us your existing code?

Comment: `not_el(X, L) :- maplist(dif(X), L).`